# Why I get "ECONNRESET" when I try to get an element from a remote html page

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to recover the price of an article on GearBest. For that, I use Cheerio to do webscraping. I created a little script (I'm using NodeJS) but I still get the same error : **"Error: read ECONNRESET"**.
I have done some research but I can't solve the error.

Here's my code :

```js
// https://www.gearbest.com/laptops/pp_786411.html')
//<span class="goodsIntro_price js-currency js-panelIntroPrice" data-currency="939.99" data-wrap="0" data-round="2">€836.60</span>
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const port = 8080;
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const request = require('request')

var url = 'https://www.gearbest.com/laptops/pp_786411.html'
request(url, (error, response, html) => {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)

        const siteHeader = $('.js-panelIntroNormalPrice')

        console.log(siteHeader.text())
    } else {
        console.log('Erreur : ' + error)
        //console.log('Http code : ' + response.statusCode)
    }
})
```

Comment: I ran your code on repl.it and I don't get an error.  I suspect the site is rejecting your request (maybe too many accesses?).  Try running on a different IP address (VPN, maybe) to see if that's the problem.

Comment: I tried with hotspot shield vpn, I don't have any mistakes but I don't have any results. No results are returned

Comment: I also tested with Repl.it, and it seems to work, even if I don't really get what I want back..

It doesn't make sense..

Comment: Try sending some headers and setting keepAlive to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appear when your connection is interrupted.

Try `curl https://www.gearbest.com/laptops/pp_786411.html` if it cannot fetch the page it is a network issue.

Comment: ok, I tried your code, and GearBest does not send response. I believe it is some mechanism to block scrapers. My advise is to try to replicate Headers and Cookies. Load the page with Browser Inspector open and copy across all the Request Headers:   

:method: GET
:path: /laptops/pp_786411.html
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
cookie:  .....  all of them. This could fool the server.

Comment: I think it can work. I'll try as soon as I can. 

Otherwise I had another solution, it was to download the page and check on the offline page. And reload it every 15 minutes, for example.

Thank you !